# Array combinations without repetition

Tags: sql, postgresql, combinatorics

I would like to make combinations out from an `int[]`

`{2,4,6,7,8,10,13,15,16,18}` should give following results:

```
2,4,6
2,4,7
2,4,8
...
15,16,18
```

Is it possible to write query only solution without using custom functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with a as (
    select i
    from unnest (array[2,4,6,7,8,10,13,15,16,18]) s(i)
)
select *
from
    a cross join a b cross join a c
where
    a < b and b < c
order by a, b, c
```