# Aggregate all combinations of rows taken k at a time

Tags: postgresql, combinatorics

I am trying to calculate an aggregate function for a field for a subset of rows in a table.  The problem is that I'd like to find the mean of every combination of rows taken k at a time --- so for all the rows, I'd like to find (say) the mean of every combination of 10 rows.  So:

```
 id | count
----|------
  1 |  5
  2 |  3
  3 |  6
...
 30 | 16
```

should give me

mean of ids 1..10; ids 1, 3..11; ids 1, 4..12, and so so.  I know this will yield a lot of rows.

There are SO answers for finding [combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899760/array-combinations-without-repetition) from arrays. I could do this programmatically by taking 30 ids 10 at a time and then `SELECT`ing them.  Is there a way to do this with `PARTITION BY`, `TABLESAMPLE`, or another function (something like python's [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations))?  (`TABLESAMPLE` by itself won't guarantee *which* subset of rows I am selecting as far as I can tell.)

Comment: The solution of @klin is really great. But your use case is crazy: Do you really need every 10 out of 30? This makes 30,045,015 data sets. This needs a huge amount of time for calculating and no one can evaluate this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described in the cited answer is static. A more convenient solution may be to use recursion.

Example data:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id int primary key, number int);
insert into my_table values
(1, 5), 
(2, 3), 
(3, 6), 
(4, 9), 
(5, 2);
```

Query which finds 2 element subsets in 5 element set (k-combination with k = 2):

```
with recursive recur as (
    select 
        id, 
        array[id] as combination, 
        array[number] as numbers, 
        number as sum
    from my_table
union all
    select 
        t.id, 
        combination || t.id, 
        numbers || t.number, 
        sum+ number
    from my_table t
    join recur r on r.id < t.id 
    and cardinality(combination) < 2            -- param k
)
select combination, numbers, sum/2.0 as average -- param k
from recur
where cardinality(combination) = 2              -- param k

 combination | numbers |      average       
-------------+---------+--------------------
 {1,2}       | {5,3}   | 4.0000000000000000
 {1,3}       | {5,6}   | 5.5000000000000000
 {1,4}       | {5,9}   | 7.0000000000000000
 {1,5}       | {5,2}   | 3.5000000000000000
 {2,3}       | {3,6}   | 4.5000000000000000
 {2,4}       | {3,9}   | 6.0000000000000000
 {2,5}       | {3,2}   | 2.5000000000000000
 {3,4}       | {6,9}   | 7.5000000000000000
 {3,5}       | {6,2}   | 4.0000000000000000
 {4,5}       | {9,2}   | 5.5000000000000000
(10 rows)
```

The same query for k = 3 gives:

```
 combination | numbers |      average       
-------------+---------+--------------------
 {1,2,3}     | {5,3,6} | 4.6666666666666667
 {1,2,4}     | {5,3,9} | 5.6666666666666667
 {1,2,5}     | {5,3,2} | 3.3333333333333333
 {1,3,4}     | {5,6,9} | 6.6666666666666667
 {1,3,5}     | {5,6,2} | 4.3333333333333333
 {1,4,5}     | {5,9,2} | 5.3333333333333333
 {2,3,4}     | {3,6,9} | 6.0000000000000000
 {2,3,5}     | {3,6,2} | 3.6666666666666667
 {2,4,5}     | {3,9,2} | 4.6666666666666667
 {3,4,5}     | {6,9,2} | 5.6666666666666667
(10 rows)
```

Of course, you can remove `numbers` from the query if you do not need them.